# how to use systemd to run a python script forever and restart if it dies halfway on raspberry pi 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, systemd

I have read that upstart is obsolete in favor of systemd for raspberry pi 3.

My question is how do I run a python script :

a) forever unless I manually kill it
b) can restart if it dies due to some exception or stop running automatically without any human intervention

my python script itself is already using modules like `schedule` and `while True` loops to keep running certain jobs every few seconds.

I am just worried that it will die/stop (which it did) after some indeterminate amount of time.

If it stops, all I want is for it to restart.

Currently, I run the script by double clicking it to open in Python IDLE (2.7) and then run module.

What is the best way to run and open a python script and let it run continuously non-stop and then have it auto restart when it dies / stops for whatever reason?

See this picture where it suddenly stops by itself at 5 plus am

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at Python Supervisor. Supervisor will manage the restart in the event of a crash or even machine re-starts.

http://supervisord.org/

Comment: It should. It is pure Python.

Comment: thanks I got it to work. I have a separate question about the print out to log regarding supervisor and my python script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604056/how-to-print-out-to-stdout-logfile-indicated-by-supervisor-if-the-command-is-run Greatly appreciate your help if you can.

Comment: Apologies. there was a slight delay in the log file... now it's showing. I have deleted that question. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

An easier method might be the handle the failure within your script.  If it is failing due to some exception, wrap the offending code in a try:except block and handle it gracefully within the script.

That said, this post has the information you need to use systemd to execute a BASH script:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd

Within your script, you can easily run a python script and catch its return value (when it returns failure in your case) and react appropriately.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
python ~/path/to/my/script/myScript.py

if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then #handle the failure here.
```

If that won't work either, you can create a script whose sole job is to call the other script and handle its failures, and use systemd to call *that* script.

Comment: i have handled the exception. the issue is that the script sometimes just stops all of a sudden on its own.